# Display result GeoQuerySet

Tags: postgis, geodjango

I'm trying to query my PostGis database thanks to geoDjango but I have an error where I found no solution on the internet.

```
    close_loc=PlanetOsmPoint.objects.get(way__distance_lte=(lePoint, D(**distance_from_point)))
```

Whatever I try on the result (close_loc) with a print, I have this error :

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: Only lon/lat coordinate systems are supported in geography.
```

I tried to convert it to a correct format thanks to transform(SRID) but nothing was solved, still the same problem.

Here's some informations :

Transformation :

```
sr1=SpatialReference('54004')
sr2=SpatialReference('NAD83')
ct=CoordTransform(sr1, sr2)
```

What I'm doing after getting the close_loc :

```
close_loc.transform(ct)
print close_loc[0]
```

close_loc type is GeoQuerySet. 
How can I exploit this result ?

Answer (score 1):

The transform() function expects an integer, not a string. The correct syntax is:

> close_loc.transform( new_srid_number )

In your case, something like this:

> close_loc.transform(54004)

Hope it'll work !